# How to delete data by mask in Javascript using .replace or something else?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting data in the form of date and time:

```
Monday Jan 23 10:14:27 2024
```

How in Javascript using .replace to remove everything except time without seconds:

```
10:14
```

.

Please tell me, because I am already lost in these regular expressions.
Thank you all.

Comment: `I am already lost in these regular expressions.` so lost, you've posted NONE

Comment: That string is parsable to a Date object at (least in my locale) so you shouldn't need to use regex at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const reg = /\d{2}:\d{2}/
const str = 'Monday Jan 23 10:14:27 2024'
const time = str.match(reg)[0]
console.log(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply convert this string to date and extract the required information from it.

```
const theDate = new Date('Monday Jan 23 10:14:27 2024');
const displayValue = `${theDate.getHours()}:${theDate.getMinutes()}`;

console.log(displayValue); // 10:14
```

Comment: You forgot to convert the string to date

Comment: Tak.. Edited already.. Dziękuję